# How to slice an input in keras?

Tags: keras, reshape

I give to keras an input of shape `input_shape=(500,)`.

For some reasons, I would like to decompose the input vector into to vectors of respective shapes `input_shape_1=(300,)` and `input_shape_2=(200,)`

I want to do this within the definition of the model, using the Functional API. In a way, I would like to perform slicing on a `tf.Tensor` object.

Help is welcome!

Answer (score 4):

If it's just the input you like to decompose, you can preprocess the input data and use two input layers:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

inputs_first_half = tf.keras.Input(shape=(300,))
inputs_second_half = tf.keras.Input(shape=(200,))

# do something with it
first_half = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs_first_half)
second_half = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs_second_half)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Add()([first_half, second_half])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs_first_half,inputs_second_half],outputs=outputs)

data = np.random.randn(10,500)
out = model.predict([data[:,:300],data[:,300:]])
```

If you like to split after the input layer you could try reshaping and cropping, e.g,:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(500,))

# do something
intermediate = tf.keras.layers.Dense(500,activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)

# split vector with cropping
intermediate = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((500,1), input_shape=(500,))(intermediate)

first_half = tf.keras.layers.Cropping1D(cropping=(0,200))(intermediate)
first_half = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((300,), input_shape=(300,1))(first_half)

second_half = tf.keras.layers.Cropping1D(cropping=(300,0))(intermediate)
second_half = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((200,), input_shape=(200,1))(second_half)


# do something with decomposed vectors
first_half = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu)(first_half)
second_half = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu)(second_half)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Add()([first_half, second_half])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

data = np.random.randn(10,500)
out = model.predict(data)
```

The [`Cropping1D()`](https://keras.io/api/layers/reshaping_layers/cropping1d/) function expects a three-dimensional input `(batch_size, axis_to_crop, features)` and only crops along the first dimension, therefore we need to add "pseudo-dimension" to our vector by reshaping it.

Comment: It may be appropriate to replace `Add()` with `Concatenate()` because Add() layer will not concatenate the inputs.